# Selenium webdriver tests with PHP and Codeception stops mid test with no error message

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I got this this test:

```
<?php
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('ensure that user can log in to Nova.');
$I->amOnPage('/'); 
$I->see('ABC');

// Login
$I->fillField("//input[@name='email']", "test@mail.com");  //<-- Test stops here!
$I->wait(1000);
$I->fillField("//input[@name='password']", "Apassword");
$I->click("//input[@name='save']");
$I->see("Test");
?>
```

The test execution on fills in the email field, and then it stops. If I switch the password field with the email field, only the password is entered in respective field and then the test stops. Code looks fine to me. Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Just for testing purposes, does it work if you remove the `wait()`? What happens if you put `echo`s between the fill fields?

Comment: Same behaviour without the wait. An echo between fields does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the wait command won't work since it stops before even reaching the wait command.
As just for testing purpose aswell have you tried to use:

```
 $I->wait(1000);
```

Before

```
$I->fillField("//input[@name='email']", "test@mail.com");  //<-- Test stops here!
```

or does it actually fill in the email and fail to fill in the password?

Sorry couldn't comment only answer ><